# How to properly divide values in each tuple and don't amend structure

Tags: python, algorithm, lambda, pyspark

I have a list of files, I split each file on a list of words and calculated the quantity of each word in a file; My tuple now looks like:

> [('fileName1',[('word1',n), ('word2',n), ('word3',n), ('word4',n)],
>   [('fileName2',[('word1',n), ('word2',n), ('word3',n), ('word4',n)],
>   ...
>   [('fileNameM',[('word1',n), ('word2',n), ('word3',n), ('word4',n)]]

(n - number of words in a file)
Now I need to divide each n (for each fileName) into total number like: 
(tn - total number)

> [('fileNameM',[('word1',n/tn), ('word2',n/tn), ('word3',n/tn),
>   ('word4',n/tn)]]

And don't change structure of the tuple

I managed to create new RDD like:

> [(('fileNameM',[('word1',n), ('word2',n), ('word3',n), ('word4',n)]), tn]

by

```
newRDD = oldRDD.map(lambda f: (f,sum(n for w,n in f[1]))
```

But if you have a look attentively, the structure of tuble changed significantly and it doesn't solve my issue.

I'm tried this one but still have troubles.

```
newRDD = oldRDD.map(lambda f: (f[0], [w,n/sum(n for w,n in f[1]) for w,n in f[1]]))
```

Many thanks

Comment: `oldRDD.map(lambda f: (f[0], f[1].map(lambda inp: (inp[0], inp[1]/f[1].length)), f[1].length))`

Comment: @mrsrinivas you might want to use something other than the `in` keyword for your lambda.

Comment: @not_a_robot: thank you. I was just thinking of approach and forgot the keyword :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, but I need to divide inp[1] into the sum of all inp[1] in this file

Comment: also, I have error:  'list' object has no attribute 'map'